# jquery multiple select empty validate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to validate the multiple selects to see if an option was selected... if no option is selected i want a jquery popup error alert stating to select one of the options but i can only figure out how todo this with a single select...not multiple like below:

```
<select name="sickFull[0]" class="select2 sickfull">
<option></option>
<option value="1">Full day</option>
<option value="2">Half day (AM)</option>
<option value="3">Half day (PM)</option>
</select>

<select name="sickFull[1]" class="select2 sickfull">
<option></option>
<option value="1">Full day</option>
<option value="2">Half day (AM)</option>
<option value="3">Half day (PM)</option>
</select>
```

my jquery:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
        var sickfull        = $(".sickfull").val();
        var errormessage    = "";

        if (sickfull == "")
            errormessage = "Please select an option";

        if (errormessage != "") {
            $.Zebra_Dialog(errormessage, { 'type': 'warning', 'title': 'Error', 'width': '500' });
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your code should be working correctly. Your method of checking for an empty `val()` will work on both single and multi select fields. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle illustrating your issue?

Comment: ok sorry.. the problem is actually even when both selects have an option selected the errormessage "please select an option" is still being alerted which it shouldnt if both selects have an option selected

Comment: @rubberchicken try running a different check for your `if` see my answer

Comment: Set you up with one that doesn't care how any selects you have with that same class @rubberchicken - as long as one is selected you're ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run your check on all `sickfull` classes

You should also run a different check on `sickfull` that will check if something is selected.

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {

    $('.sickfull').each(function(){
        var sickfull        = $(this).val();
        var errormessage    = "";

        if (!sickfull)
            errormessage = "Please select an option";

        if (errormessage != "") {
            $.Zebra_Dialog(errormessage, { 'type': 'warning', 'title': 'Error', 'width': '500' });
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: ive tried this but still getting zebra-error-alert when both selects have options selected

Comment: @rubberchicken works for me : http://jsfiddle.net/cvqDW/ (just hit run after every submit...I have no post method)

Comment: hmm let me check my code... if it works for you it must be something wrong with me! lol

Comment: use the console (f12) to check and see if you have any errors. You can also use the console to check the values of the elements once the page has already run... just put this in the console line `$('.sickfull').each(function(){ console.log("1 - " + $(this).val());});`

Answer (score 0):

I did something a little different and allows for any number of `select` elements with the same class - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/X6GT4/

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sickfullCheckSum = 0;
    var sickfullElements = $(this).find('.sickfull').length; // how many elements could be selected?
    $('.sickfull').each(function() {
        ( '' == $(this).val() ? sickfullCheckSum++ : sickfullCheckSum-- ); // change the checksum as appropriate
    });
    (sickfullCheckSum == sickfullElements ? console.log('please select something') : console.log('good') ); // test the checksum against the elements       
});
```

Of course you can add you own error handling to the function, but this should give you a start. The key here is for `sickfullCheckSum` to not be equal to `sickfullElements`, indicating that at least one option was selected from any number of selects with the class `.sickfull`.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `.val()` to get the value of multiple fields. Your selector is returning two elements, so you need to examine each element to get its correspoding value.

```
var sickfull = $(".sickfull");

sickfull.each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        // set your error message
        return false; // stop looping
    }
}

if (errormessage != "") {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This stops if it finds one value empty, it needs to know if both are.